Retrofit with coroutine always gives kotlin.Unit exception, how to get java exception in api call failure
I am using Retrofit for API calls on Android with coroutine i.e. all my API functions in ApiService interface are suspend functions and return types are the actual data I am expecting in success scenario.
class ApiService {
    suspend fun getData() : Data
    suspend fun getUser() : User
}

I call these APIs as below in my ViewModel classes.
class UserViewModel : ViewModel () {
    fun user() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val user = service.getUser()
        } catch (e:Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG,"user: $e")
        }
        
    }
}

When there's any issue in API call, the exception block executes but it always gives same output exception:
user: kotlin.Unit

For example in case of when internet is turned off, it should throw UnknownHostException but it never gives such java exceptions, it always returns kotlin.Unit exception.
Even if I implement a custom interceptor class and wrap the chain.proceed() call in try-catch block, there as well it always gives kotlin.Unit exception.
How can we get the Java exceptions to know the specific root cause of the error?
